# Migration from local EF database to Google Cloud

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, google-cloud-sql

**Story :**

I am trying to create an ASP.NET application hosted on Google Cloud.

This application needs database access to store some data and I am already using Entity Framework to access a local database.

So I am following this tutorial, hoping to find a way to host my database on Google Cloud :
https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql

But in the Configuring settings's part during the sixth step I get an error.

**Configuration :**

File : Web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="GoogleCloudSamples:ProjectId" value="area-185910" />
    <add key="GoogleCloudSamples:BookStore" value="mysql" />
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AreaDbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AreaModel.csdl|res://*/Models.AreaModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.AreaModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\AreaDb.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="LocalMySqlServer" connectionString="Server=IP;Database=NAME;Uid=USERNAME;Pwd=USERPWD" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Error :**

[Visual studio Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/102tp.png)

Website's page's error :

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
```

**Question :**

Is someone able to explain how to make a database migration from a local EF database (with Entity Framework) to Google Cloud ?

Or is someone able to solve the error ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: EF and migrations are not my area of expertise but nobody else is jumping in so... Migrations are a development-time process, shouldn't you not run migrations when you deploy to GCP?

Comment: To deploy my applicaion to GCP I just need to make a right click on my project, then click **Publish on Google Cloud** and finally answer a little form. Nowhere in it speaks about database... I found a way to create a new database connection in the **Tools > Google Cloud Tools > Show Google Cloud Explorer**. But before to start that I need to install **MySQL for visual studio**. And it does not look like easy...